# Replica of point layer data from attribute value in QGIS

Tags: qgis, interpolation, features, vector-layer

I am working in QGIS 3.2 and am wondering how I can create an "exploded" version of a single layer of point data based on numerical attribute values within that layer.

As a simple example, let's suppose my layer has only three points: A, B, and C. Each point feature has a numerical attribute corresponding to something random and unimportant. Let's say Points A, B, & C have, respectively, values of 5, 10, and 15.

Is there a way to "explode" the layer by converting the layer of **three** points into a layer of **30** points corresponding to each point's original value? So, (former) Point A is "exploded" into 5 points, (former) Point B is "exploded" to 10 points, and (former) Point C is "exploded" to 15 points. The resulting layer would still *look* like only 3 points since it would effectively be a bunch of points superimposed onto each other at the exact location of what used to be Points A, B, & C.

I know there are point interpolation methods that can give me a raster output showing the contours of the attribute values at these 3 points. And if interpolation is really the only way to visualize data like this, so be it. Just wondering if there is an alternative way to visualize by "exploding" the original layer in this way.

Comment: This seems like a fairly manual process - what if the numerical values were higher than this example? How to duplicate it x number of times if the value of that point is x?

Comment: I think the easiest way is to use a script.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following script does the job:

```py
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Layer_Name')[0]
name_field = 'Name' # not mandatory
count_field = 'Count' # numerical field, mandatory

# make new empty layer and copy the fields
crs = layer.crs().authid()
new_layer = QgsVectorLayer("Point?crs=" + crs, "Exploded", "memory")
new_layer.dataProvider().addAttributes(layer.fields())
new_layer.updateFields()

# copy features 
for feature in layer.getFeatures():
    count = feature[count_field]
    new_layer.dataProvider().addFeatures([feature]*count)
    
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(new_layer)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Let's assume there is a point layer called *'Centroids'* with three features in it, see the image below. The field `"Number"` will be used for producing copies of each feature.

[image: input]

**Step 1.** Apply the ["Array of translated features"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html#array-of-translated-features) geoalgortihm ([available in QGIS 3.4](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog34/index.html#feature-array-of-translated-features-algorithm)). In the `'Number of features to create'` field use the following expression:

```
"Number" - 1
```

[image: step1]

**Step 2. [Optional]** Make use of the ["Collect geometries"](https://docs.qgis.orglatest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html?highlight=singlepart#collect-geometries) tool with `"id"` as the `'Unique ID fields [optional]'`. And get the output like this:

[image: result]

Delete with the ["Drop field(s)"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectortable.html#drop-field-s) irrelevant fields if needed.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use `Menu Processing > Toolbox > Geometry by expression` ([see documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/de/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression)) with this expression:

   ```
   collect_geometries(
       array_foreach(
           generate_series (1, "Number"),
           make_point ($y,$y)
       )
   )
   ```
2. Run `Menu Vector > Geometry Tools > Multipart to single parts`.

You're done.